# MariaDB stored proc - Getting an error 'Missing SELECT' on INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

While I created loads of procs in SQL server, I want to start using MariaDB and so tried creating the simple proc below in MySQL Workbench.

I keep on getting an error stating that there is a missing SELECT on the opening '(' after the table name:

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists usp_AddSentEmail$$
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_AddSentEmail (in pSender varchar(36)
    ,in pTo varchar(1000)
    ,in pSubject varchar(100)
    ,in pBody varchar(10000)
    ,in pRecordDT datetime)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Emails('To','Subject','Body','Sender','RecordDT','Sent','SentDT') 
        VALUES (pTo,pSubject,pBody,pSender,pRecordDT,1,pRecordDT);

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Maybe I am trying the wrong google search but that all comes up is delimiter errors.

Comment: note that columns are not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the quotes from the column names in your insert query:

```
INSERT INTO Emails(To,Subject,Body,Sender,RecordDT,Sent,SentDT) 
    VALUES (pTo,pSubject,pBody,pSender,pRecordDT,1,pRecordDT);
```

Comment: Hah. You okes are genius :-) Thanks. I had to put the To and Subject in backticks but the rest was all fine.